# Timers session value extracted with Lua

Tags: lua, haproxy

In documentation about [Timing events](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#8.4) can be observed values like Ta/Tr/Tw/Td. A general question is how can correspondence of such values can be extracted in some additional code, like Lua one.